# Core Graphics - Shadow not seen

Tags: ios, core-graphics, shadow

I wrote a simple drawRect with a intention of drawing a circle, drop a shadow and fill it with blue. I have successfully achieved drawing a circle and filling it in blue but my shadow is not in effect. Instead of fill if I stroke my circle, i see the shadow is inside the circle and during fill it is drawn over by fill colour

rect to my drawRect has dimension [[CustomButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];

```
@implementation CustomButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGColorRef colorRef = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, colorRef);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);


CGRect buttonRect = CGRectInset(rect, 3, 3);

CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(buttonRect  ),     CGRectGetMidY(buttonRect));
CGFloat radius = CGRectGetWidth(buttonRect) / 2;

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(15.0, 20.0), 1.0);
CGContextAddArc(context, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, radius, 0, 2*M_PI, 1);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextFillRect(context, buttonRect);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);


CGColorRelease(colorRef);

}

@end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorRef colorRef = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, colorRef);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);


    CGRect buttonRect = CGRectInset(rect, 3, 3);

    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(buttonRect  ),     CGRectGetMidY(buttonRect));
    CGFloat radius = CGRectGetWidth(buttonRect) / 2;

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0), 2.0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, radius, 0, 2*M_PI, 1);
    //CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);


    CGColorRelease(colorRef);
}
```

Your shadow was rectangular and that is why it was not seen under the circle. I changed the call `CGContextFillRect` to `CGContextFillPath`, the path which you already create using `CGContextAddArc`.

Is this what you were going for?

**EDIT**

You can find a project here: https://bitbucket.org/reydan/so_circleshadow